# Rolling 12 month data Sum operation

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, rolling-computation

I have seen rolling 12's on averages and counts, but not on a sum.

I have a table like so

```
ID | Profile_ID | EntryLocation | EntryMonth   |    Usage 
----------------------------------------------------------- 
1  |    1       |   11          |   2019-06-01 |    60.00  
2  |    1       |   12          |   2019-05-01 |    40.00  
3  |    1       |   11          |   2019-05-01 |    30.00  
4  |    2       |   11          |   2019-06-01 |   100.00 
5  |    1       |   12          |   2019-06-01 |    74.00  
6  |    2       |   12          |   2019-06-01 |   456.00 
7  |    2       |   11          |   2019-05-01 |    33.00 
8  |    1       |   11          |   2019-07-01 |   200.00 
9  |    1       |   11          |   2018-06-01 |   100.00
```

And what I want to do is sum up the usage all the previous months, grouping on `Profile_ID`,`EntryLocation`, and `EntryMonth` (which make up a clustered primary key (i.e. the combination of the three is unique).

So the result I am looking for would be the following:

```
ID | Profile_ID | EntryLocation | EntryMonth   |    Rolling12Usage 
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  |    1       |   11          |   2018-06-01 |   100.00  
2  |    1       |   11          |   2019-05-01 |   130.00 --> (100 + 30) 
3  |    1       |   11          |   2019-06-01 |    90.00 -->(30 + 60 (note the 100 fell off))
4  |    1       |   11          |   2019-07-01 |   290.00 -->(90 + 200)
5  |    1       |   12          |   2019-05-01 |    40.00  
6  |    1       |   12          |   2019-06-01 |   114.00 -->(40 + 74)
7  |    2       |   11          |   2019-05-01 |    33.00  
8  |    2       |   11          |   2019-06-01 |   133.00 -->(33 + 100)
9  |    2       |   12          |   2019-06-01 |   456.00
```

I have tried this with grouping

```
select x.Profile_ID, x.EntryLocation, x.EntryMonth, sum(Usage) as [SumUsage],
       (sum(sum(Usage)) over (order by x.EntryMonth rows between 11 preceding and current row) 
       ) as Sum_12month
from my_table_with_values x
group by x.EntryMonth, x.Profile_ID, x.EntryLocation
order by x.EntryMonth
```

But couldn't get the ordering right. Any ideas/help?

Bonus points if you want to add the solution for doing it WITHOUT assuming a clustered primary key on those values (I bet that situation may be more/as common as mine).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a `partition by`:

```
select x.Profile_ID, x.EntryLocation, x.EntryMonth, sum(Usage) as [SumUsage],
       sum(sum(Usage)) over (partition by Profile_ID, EntryLocation
                             order by x.EntryMonth
                             rows between 11 preceding and current row
                            ) as Sum_12month
from my_table_with_values x
group by x.EntryMonth, x.Profile_ID, x.EntryLocation
order by x.EntryMonth;
```

If you don't have all months, you can use `range` instead of `rows`:

```
select x.Profile_ID, x.EntryLocation, x.EntryMonth, sum(Usage) as [SumUsage],
       sum(sum(Usage)) over (partition by Profile_ID, EntryLocation
                             order by x.EntryMonth
                             range between interval 11 month preceding and current row
                            ) as Sum_12month
from my_table_with_values x
group by x.EntryMonth, x.Profile_ID, x.EntryLocation
order by x.EntryMonth;
```

Comment: Yes! That is part of it. Now the only issue it will grab all the possible rows it can up to 11 rather than just grabbing the last 11 months. (I was secretly hoping you @gordon_linoff would answer because one of your previous answers is what I was modeling off of!)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT x.Profile_ID, 
       x.EntryLocation,
       x.Entry_Month,
       SUM(x2.Usage)
  FROM my_table_with_values x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table_with_values x2
    ON x.Profile_id = x2.Profile_id
   AND x.Entry_Location x2.Entry_Location
   AND x2.Entry_Month BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -11, x.entrymonth)
        And x.entrymonth 
 GROUP
    BY x.Profile_ID, 
       x.EntryLocation,
       x.Entry_Month
```

Comment: that seems really close. I am getting a null in the sum(x2.usage) column though... there can be null values possibly. Perhaps that is causing it? Or the join is just not working quite like it should?

Comment: @thalacker Yeah, it looks like your proposed edit works